# How do I change the arrow function when I replace a class with a function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Replaced `class A` with a function. I don't get an error when I build with a webpack, but it doesn't work properly. Of course, it works well when it's `class A`, but it doesn't work normally only when it's changed to `function A` as shown below. The most suspect part is `this.updateBind()` function inside the `init()` method. It's an arrow function inside the class, so I think there might be a problem when I change the class to a function. I will not upload the entire source because I have to include the library and build it with a webpack. This is because the `main.js` and `vender.js` files in the `/dist` folder are hard to read. I think `this.updateBind()` function might have caused the problem, is my guess correct? How should I handle the arrow function when converting `class A` to `function A`?

```
class A extends B {
  constructor(m) {
    super(m);
  }
  init() {
    this.updateBind = () => {
      this.update();
    }
    window.addEventListener('resizeEnd', this.updateBind);
  }
  update() {
    this.scroll.update();
  }
  destroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('resizeEnd', this.updateBind);
    this.scroll.destroy();
  }
}
```

Source that replaced Class A with Function A

```
function A(m) {
  B.call(this, m);
}
A.prototype.init = function() {
  this.updateBind = () => {
    this.update();
  }
  window.addEventListener('resizeEnd', this.updateBind);
}
A.prototype.update = function() {
  this.scroll.update();
}
A.prototype.destroy = function() {
  window.removeEventListener('resizeEnd', this.updateBind);
  this.scroll.destroy();
}

A.prototype = Object.create(B.prototype);
A.prototype.constructor = B;
```

Comment: @MichaelM. I think that's the whole point of defining `this.updateBind` -- it keeps the `this` context from `init()`. They're emulating what `this.update.bind(this)` would do.

Comment: "*Replaced class A with a function.*" - but why? Also, what is `B`, is it a `class`?

Comment: "*it doesn't work properly.*" - what exactly is the problem? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: @Bergi `B` belongs to the library, but I think it's a function. There is no error message at all, but it did not work properly. As I received @Michael M.'s answer, it is a bug caused by overwriting the `A.prototype` after defining the `A.prototype` methods, and it has now been completely solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue isn't your arrow function, but how you're inheriting `B` via the prototype. When you do this line:

```
A.prototype = Object.create(B.prototype);
```

you overwrite all the other methods else previously in `A.prototype`, so every method becomes `undefined`. Expand the snippet below to see this issue:

```js
function B(m) {
  console.log('B constructor', m);
}

function A(m) {
  B.call(this, m);
}

A.prototype.init = function() {
  this.updateBind = () => {
    this.update();
  }
  window.addEventListener('resizeEnd', this.updateBind);
}
A.prototype.update = function() {
  this.scroll.update();
}
A.prototype.destroy = function() {
  window.removeEventListener('resizeEnd', this.updateBind);
  this.scroll.destroy();
}
A.prototype = Object.create(B.prototype); // problem here
A.prototype.constructor = B;

const test = new A(1);
console.log(test.update); // undefined
```

To fix this, just move that line above the rest of the method definitions, like this:

```js
function B(m) {
  console.log('B constructor', m);
}

function A(m) {
  B.call(this, m);
}
A.prototype = Object.create(B.prototype); // moved up
A.prototype.constructor = B;              // moved up
A.prototype.init = function() {
  this.updateBind = () => {
    this.update();
  }
  window.addEventListener('resizeEnd', this.updateBind);
}
A.prototype.update = function() {
  this.scroll.update();
}
A.prototype.destroy = function() {
  window.removeEventListener('resizeEnd', this.updateBind);
  this.scroll.destroy();
}

const test = new A(1);
console.log(test.update); // not undefined anymore
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I did what you told me and it works perfectly. Thank you very much.